# Can't reference Holo theme from values-v11/themes.xml

Tags: android, xml, themes

I'm trying to make my app use the Holo Light theme if it is running on a 3.0+ device, but for some reason the values-v11 method isn't working. I see a bunch of other people apparently using this method, but when I define my theme in res/values-v11/themes.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="MainStyle" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light">

</style>
</resources>
```

Eclipse gives me `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:Theme.Holo.Light'.` It's the same whether I use `android:Theme.Holo.Light` or `android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`.

My minSdkVersion is set to 10 and my targetSdkVersion is set to 15.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect you should be using `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`. Make sure it's exactly like this--with the `@` sign and everything.

*From comments*: Also make sure you've set your target API (different from the target SDK) in the Project Properties (not the manifest) to be at least 4.0/API 14.

Comment: Using `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` gives me the same message.

Comment: Have you cleaned your project? What does your manifest look like? Are you using the `MainStyle` there?

Comment: I commented out the troublesome line and cleaned my project, but it still didn't work. For one of my activities `android:theme` is set to `@style/MainStyle`, but that doesn't seem to be a problem. The problem seems to be in `values-v11/themes.xml`. If you want to see my manifest you can look at it here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53423033/AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Is your build target set to 14+ in the Project Properties? (Not the manifest.)

Comment: No, it wasn't. :) It was set to 2.3.3 because I didn't think that it would be able to run on anything prior to 4.0, but I tested it (on a 2.3.3 device) and I was wrong! Yay! I guess it does make sense that as long as minSdkVersion is set to allow 2.3.3, it will work. Oh well, newbie mistake. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad it worked! I've amended my answer to reflect this; don't forget to mark it as accepted if it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set your Project Build Target above or equal to 14 and make sure you used correct syntax for Theme.Holo.Light.
It should be like this
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"

Answer (score 0):

TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title appears to have been added in API Level 13. Make sure your build target is set to 13, not just 11.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion=...
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```